# Spring Data JPA Native SQL Query DELETE SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I use `@Modifying` annotation together with `@Query` annotation to perform `SQL DELETE` query and delete the record from a database table.

```java
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS  where CUSTOMERS.ID =:customersId and CUSTOMERS.USER_ID  = :userId and CUSTOMERS.USER_ID  = :sellerId", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteContributeur(@Param("customersId") Long customersId, @Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("sellerId") Long sellerId);
```

Error:

> Exception in xxx.xxx.xx with cause =
>   'javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query' and exception = 'Executing an update/delete
>   query; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query'

Comment: is this part correct "CUSTOMERS.USER_ID  = :userId and CUSTOMERS.USER_ID  = :sellerId""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate the service method with `@Transactional`.
Your query is wrong. Try this:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS  where CUSTOMERS.ID =:customersId and CUSTOMERS.USER_ID  IN (:userId,:sellerId)", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteContributeur(@Param("customersId") Long customersId, @Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("sellerId") Long sellerId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a transaction to run this query. There are many ways, but the simplest one would be to annotate the service method with `@Transactional`. But remember it hat to be `public` and invoked from other bean (wrapped in proxy).

Answer (score 1):

It's transactional problem - you need to add `@Transactional`. See [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/).

Answer (score 1):

Method had default visibility. Therefore the proxy mechanism was not active! After changing to public everthing works as expected!

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS  where CUSTOMERS.ID =:customersId and CUSTOMERS.USER_ID  = :userId and CUSTOMERS.USER_ID  = :sellerId", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteContributeur(@Param("customersId") Long customersId, @Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("sellerId") Long sellerId);
```

I use the @Transactional annotation from Spring package like `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` Then it should work